# System.ServiceModel missing

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm working with VS2010 express on Win7 (64 bit) and I'm trying use `System.ServiceModel` but I get an error that there is no `ServiceModel` in the `System` namespace:

> The type or namespace name 'ServiceModel' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I looked in `\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319` and there are some `ServiceModel___.dll` files but I don't know if I'm missing something or if they are corrupted.

Any advice?

Thanks,
Yonatan

Comment: Did you add a reference to it? Select Project-> Add Reference and select the assembly name.

Comment: yep...didn't do that. THANKS !

Comment: Here is a similar problem. I solved using this method.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7511199/system-servicemodel-dll-missing-in-references-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Add a reference to the assembly System.ServiceModel. Select **Project**-> **Add Reference** and then select the assembly name.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Helped me alot!

Comment: Does not appear to be an option in 2021.

Answer (score 15):

Right click on **Project** -> Properties -> Application -> Target Framework = .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 6):

The `System.ServiceModel` namespace is in System.ServiceModel.dll.

I'm not running 64 bit Windows so I can't check whether that's the right location.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes Visual Studio doesn't install this dll in GAC.
You can gac what is located in %systemDrive%\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 using `gacutil /i dll_file`
To use gacutil you can open Command Prompt from Visual Studio Tools menu.

Comment: I think you mean gacutil /l ?