# Cannot reference System.ServiceModel in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to use the [WCF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf) in my Unity project, therefore I need to reference dll `System.ServiceModel`. Also, these are some more info on my environment:

- Unity 2018.1.5f1 Personal (64bit)
- Windows 10 (64bit)

#### Using msc.rsp

Following the [Unity doc on loading external assemblies](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileAssemblies.html), I have created the `msc.rsp` file inside my `Assets/` directory:

```
-r:System.ServiceModel.dll
```

In my `Assets/` folder I also have a C# file which needs the WCF:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Description;

public class CommunicationEndpoint {
    private const short Port = 8000;
    private ServiceHost host;

    public void Start() {
        this.EnsureInitilized();
        host.Open();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        if (this.host != null) return;
        host.Close();
    }

    private void EnsureInitilized() {
        if (this.host != null) return;

        this.host = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommunicationService));
        host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICommunicationService), new BasicHttpBinding(), Address);

        host.Open();
    }

    private string Address {
        get { return "http://localhost:" + Port; }
    }
}
```

There is another file where interface `ICommunicationService` is defined, still part of the assets inside `Assets/`. Did not report here as it is not that useful.

#### Still compile errors

Basically, nothing happens in Unity: I still get errors at compile time where clearly the assembly was not loaded at all.

[image: Errors in Unity]

**Note** I have also re-imported all by right-clicking on the `Assets` pane in Unity and clicking on `Reimport All` to make sure the C# project gets regenerated. I can see it is regenerated, but still nothing changes: same issues.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you tried adding a reference to the assembly? check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5647493/1287916

Comment: Shouldn't Unity take care of adding that reference? If I do that, next time I make a change and Unity regenerates the C# project, my manual changes will be overriden.

Comment: Directly changing the C# project I think is wrong because it is a generated file. If something happens I lose my changes

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, Visual Studio has no more issues and I can compile, but back to Unity, the errors are still there. When I refresh in Unity, the project gets regenerated and my changes are gone and the errors are back in Visual Studio too. I don't think that can be a valid approach :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried setting up a similar project where i had a `mcs.rsp` file with `-r:System.ServiceModel.dll` inside while i had a .cs reference the `ServiceModel` namespace, and i got the same issue.

After changing the project `Scripting Runtime Version` to `.NET 4.0 Equivalent`, and `Api Compability Level` to `.NET 4.x` it started working.

> If part of the API seems to be missing, it might not be included with
>   .NET Standard 2.0. The Project may need to use the .NET 4.x Api
>   Compatibility Level instead.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/dotnetProfileAssemblies.html

Comment: Ok... I have tried to find that option in unity... where do I change the `Scripting Runtime Version`? and where to I change the `API Compatibility Level`? Cannot find them sorry

Comment: Ok found it under `Player` settings :)

Comment: By any chance, do you know why `System.ServiceModel.Web.dll` is not being loaded? I have added it to the `mcs.rsp` file and reimported everything, but the generated project does not have that dll :(

Answer (score 0):

msc.rsp **do** include System.ServiceModel.dll by adding content

```
-r:System.ServiceModel.dll
```

for Unity Editor

However, there's a bug that dll reference **won't be** included in csproj : 
https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/httpclient-namespace-is-not-recognized-in-vs-with-net-4-dot-x

You can try to fix the problem by alter the csproj file by yourself : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/cross-platform/customize-project-files-created-by-vstu?view=vs-2017

reference : 
https://forum.unity.com/threads/using-dynamic-keyword-not-working.490600/

https://forum.unity.com/threads/httpclient.460748/

Answer (score 0):

For anyone currently needing to add references to certain system assemblies to Unity in recent versions (as of 2021), the correct way to do so is add a text file at `Assets\csc.rsp` and put `-r:System.ServiceModel.dll` in it, or whatever assembly you want.  You can also add #defines in this file, too.  For example: `-define:STAGING`